# Bug/Problem in windows live messenger 2011 & facebook

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

When I talk to people in facebook using messenger after I send them the message it appears several times.

for example:

I write: Hello World.
In the chat window I see:

Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World.
Hello World.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [topic](http://windowslivehelp.com/thread.aspx?threadid=07a20770-d118-44c7-b78e-6fc2acb5c15f) in windows live help website, it solved my problem.